# How to get results faster in Microsoft Excel, using conditions in VB Script?

Tags: vba, excel

I have designed a VB Script that checks the data of 65536 rows of a particular column. I'm getting the results but its very slow. Its taking more than 4 minutes to generate the results and even sometimes with exception too.

Here is the Code

```
Sub CheckAlltheRow()
  Dim rCount As Long
  Dim count As Long
  count= 1
    For rCount = 1 To 65536
       If (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rCount, 1).Value = "Product") Then
        count = count + 1
       End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here I'm checking the 65536 rows which matches with the value 'Product' but this is too slow. How can this be managed!

Comment: Bathsheba has the best answer but if that doesn't work, look into worksheet.Range("A:A").Find

Answer (score 2):

A `=COUNTIF(A:A, "Product")`, entered directly on the worksheet counts the number of instances of "Product" in column A.

This will be order of magnitudes faster than the solution in VBA.

If you *must* do this in VBA then combine the `COUNTIF` with `Application.WorksheetFunction`

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your VBA code:

```
count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1), "Product")
```